# compiling c++ program calling x11 on windows

Tags: c++, windows, x11

I think I have a c++ program (I thought it was c#) that was written to run on a unix based system. It includes X11 calls.
Is there a way for me to compile it to run on a pc under windows xp?
I have installed mingw.

It is a 'patch' program written to get a piece of hardware (A DreamCheeky usb chessboard) to allow input to the SCID chess database package (I've got that installed in the windows version but the development of it is very much unix /tcl/tk etc)

The program is as follows.
The person who wrote it may have time to create a windows version (Or I fear may not)
But I am desperate to try to get it to work on my windows laptop.

```
//compile with g++ -o monitorcheeky monitorcheeky.c -L/usr/X11R6/lib -lX11

#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <X11/Xlib.h>
#include <X11/keysym.h>
#include <string.h>

#define KEY_DOWN True
#define KEY_UP False
#define KEYCODE_a 38
#define KEYCODE_b 56
#define KEYCODE_c 54
#define KEYCODE_d 40
#define KEYCODE_e 26
#define KEYCODE_f 41
#define KEYCODE_g 42
#define KEYCODE_h 43
#define KEYCODE_1 10
#define KEYCODE_2 11
#define KEYCODE_3 12
#define KEYCODE_4 13
#define KEYCODE_5 14
#define KEYCODE_6 15
#define KEYCODE_7 16
#define KEYCODE_8 17
#define KEYCODE_EQUALS 21 
#define KEYCODE_Q 24
#define KEYCODE_R 27
#define KEYCODE_B 56
#define KEYCODE_N 57
#define KEYCODE_RTN 36

Display *dpy;


// Function to create a keyboard event
XKeyEvent createKeyEvent(Display *display, Window &win,
                           Window &winRoot, bool press,
                           int keycode, int modifiers)
{
   XKeyEvent event;

   event.display     = display;
   event.window      = win;
   event.root        = winRoot;
   event.subwindow   = None;
   event.time        = CurrentTime;
   event.x           = 1;
   event.y           = 1;
   event.x_root      = 1;
   event.y_root      = 1;
   event.same_screen = True;
   event.keycode     = keycode;
   event.state       = modifiers;

   if(press)
      event.type = KeyPress;
   else
      event.type = KeyRelease;

return event;
}

int sendKeyPress(Window winRoot, char letter, int revert) {
    Window winFocus;
    int keycode;

    switch( letter ) 
    {
      case 'a':
        keycode = KEYCODE_a;
    break;
      case 'b':
        keycode = KEYCODE_b;
    break;
      case 'c':
        keycode = KEYCODE_c;
    break;
      case 'd':
        keycode = KEYCODE_d;
    break;
      case 'e':
        keycode = KEYCODE_e;
    break;
      case 'f':
        keycode = KEYCODE_f;
    break;
      case 'g':
        keycode = KEYCODE_g;
    break;
      case 'h':
        keycode = KEYCODE_h;
    break;
      case '1':
        keycode = KEYCODE_1;
    break;
      case '2':
        keycode = KEYCODE_2;
    break;
      case '3':
        keycode = KEYCODE_3;
    break;
      case '4':
        keycode = KEYCODE_4;
    break;
      case '5':
        keycode = KEYCODE_5;
    break;
      case '6':
        keycode = KEYCODE_6;
    break;
      case '7':
        keycode = KEYCODE_7;
    break;
      case '8':
        keycode = KEYCODE_8;
    break;
      default :
    keycode = KEYCODE_RTN;
     }

    XGetInputFocus(dpy, &winFocus, &revert);
    // Send a fake key press event to the window.
    XKeyEvent event = createKeyEvent(dpy, winFocus, winRoot, KEY_DOWN, keycode, 0);
    XSendEvent(event.display, event.window, True, KeyPressMask, (XEvent *)&event);
    // Send a fake key release event to the window.
    event = createKeyEvent(dpy, winFocus, winRoot, KEY_UP, keycode, 0);
    XSendEvent(event.display, event.window, True, KeyPressMask, (XEvent *)&event);
    XFlush(dpy);
    return 0;
}

int main() {
  int sockfd;
  int len;
  struct sockaddr_in address;
  int result;
  char input[5];  
  int revert;

  /* init */
  dpy = XOpenDisplay(NULL);
  if (!dpy) return 1;
  // Get the root window for the current display.
  Window winRoot = XDefaultRootWindow(dpy);

  sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

  address.sin_family = AF_INET;
  address.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");
  address.sin_port = htons(8796);
  len = sizeof(address);

  result = connect(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&address, len);

  if (result == -1) {
    perror("oops: client1");
    return 1;
  }
  while (1) {
    read(sockfd, input ,5);
  //  printf("%s",input);
  //  fflush(stdin);

    sendKeyPress(winRoot, input[0], revert);
    sendKeyPress(winRoot, input[1], revert);
    sendKeyPress(winRoot, input[2], revert);
    sendKeyPress(winRoot, input[3], revert);
  }

  /* cleanup */
  XCloseDisplay(dpy);
  return 0;
}
```

thnx all

Jerry
Jerry

Comment: What does it use to call into X11?

Comment: More apologies! :Am unsure how to post a reply to your comment Tim. The add comment option only allows 500 characters and clearly no formatting!

Comment: Just edit your original posting and add the source code

Comment: Looking at that code it looks like it's written in C++, not C#.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

mingw will not be able to run it even if it compiles.

You will need cygwin with the X server to run.

Comment: Does that mean I will need to be running a unix-like 'shell' within my windows?

Comment: Actually no, but it's easier that way. Otherwise it's a pain in the behind to get X running right.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe, you should try "Xming" or "Cygwin/X"? I have no experience with it, but it could help.

Comment: Can you elaborate. My understanding from quickly looking at the xming site is that xming allows x-windows type apllications to run. I don't think i've got that. I've got source code which needs access to x11 libairies in order to compile.

Comment: @JerryK:  Once it compiles, what do you intend to do with it?  If you don't have the libraries, or they don't work, the compiled code seems to me to be useless.

Comment: When the monitorcheeky program is compiled 'correctly'(ie all the functionality of the x11 procedures etc  has been compiled 'into' the executable code surely when the program is run it will do what it is designed to do: that is pickup data coming in via the usb port where the usb chessboad is attached and 'pass it on' to the scid program (which i'd also have running on my pc) The person who wrote the code has it working exactly like that on his unix/linnux system.

Comment: You are aware that it can only send to a SCID program compiled with X11 right?

Comment: NO! My best understanding is that the SCID package does not have any calls to x11! But what you highlight makes sense. If i look at all the source code of SCID (its open source) and find no call to x11 would you say "impossible"?

Comment: I just checked. The Linux version uses X11, as would any other GUI program on Linux. You could try source compiling both on Cygwin and see if it works or not.

Comment: What depressing news! But thanks Joshua for straightening out my wishful thinking. I'm going to have to go back to relying on the author of monitorcheeky to provide a windows version. But from what i have learned here I fear 'he may be gone a long time'